# How to sort titles in a toctree using glob?

Tags: sorting, python-sphinx, glob, toctree

I need to sort my `toctree` by titles. I use `:glob:` property, and it sorts only on my filename.

Do you have a solution ?

Exemple :

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :titlesonly:
   :glob:

   myfile1.rst
   myfile2.rst
```

myfile1.rst

```
BBBB
=====
```

myfile2.rst

```
AAAA
=====
```

I obtain in my HTML page :

```
BBBB
AAAA
```

and I would like to have :

```
AAAA
BBBB
```

Answer (score 1):

`glob` is unnecessary because you don't use a globbing expression.

You can manually sort the files in the [`toctree` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree).  File extensions are unnecessary.

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1
    :titlesonly:

    myfile2
    myfile1
```

Comment: It's a problem, because of my list of file is about 90 elements.

Comment: You cannot do both glob and manual sorting. Globbing matches and sorts on filename, not the content of files. Also your question omitted any globbing expression, so you are not using it even with the `:glob:` option. The only option is to rename your files into an order that will sort in the order you desire.